# Is weighted linear regression best way to do this?

Tags: machine-learning, python, dataset

I have an array of 316 points (from a map) that have 64 values (various data from the map) that describe each of those points.

I will then get 1000+ points from a region of the map that will also have 64 values and i need to find out if those points match criteria from those 316 points i mentioned earlier.

So i figured i might need weighted linear regression here (as i also need to exclude some of those points because of old data) from that 316 array and see if those 1000+ points fit the model.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Then you need to tell us the real-world problem you want to solve, in english.

Comment: okay, will do right now.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen there ya go...what do you think?

Comment: What does match mean here? Have the same 64 means in both regions? Or have the same distribution for 64 variables? Or something else?

Comment: distribution, not means.

Comment: You are looking for a two-sample multivariate equality of distributions test. I do not know of one that would work well on this little data, but simultaneous quantile regressions may work if comparing a few quantiles suffices.